# C++ pointer to template function which class member

Tags: c++, templates, function, pointers

I have the following functions in class "C"

```
class C
{
  template<typename T> void Func1(int x);
  template<typename T> void Func2(int x);
};

template<typename T> void C::Func1(int x)
{
  T a(x);
}

template<typename T> void C::Func2(int x)
{
  T a(x);
}
```

The functions uses templates only in the implementation. The signature does not contain template parameters.

Is it possible to define pointers to such template functions?

I tried the following definition but it results compilation error.

`typedef template<typename T> void (СSomeClass::*TFuncPtr)(int);`

Comment: Does it work without the typedef?

Comment: Stop calling them template functions. They are function templates. It does make a difference (no, I am not willing to explain to somebody who does not accept answers).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once instantiated, a member function template is just a normal member function, so you can use a normal member function pointer (best `typedef`'d like below):

```
typedef void (C::*mem_fun_ptr)(int);
mem_fun_ptr p = &C::Func1<Bar>;
//          IMPORTANT -- ^^^^^
```

The underlined part is the important part. You can't make a pointer to a function template, but you can make a pointer to an *instantiated* function template.

Answer (score 4):

do you want only a pointer to a function?
that's simple:

```
class C
{
public:
  template<typename T> void Func1(int x);
};

typedef void (C::*TFuncPtr)(int);

int main()
{
 TFuncPtr ptr = &C::Func1<int>;
}
```

if you want something else could you show an example of using the pointer you want?

Comment: You answer completely matches my question. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask read the part about accepting answers: "When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer."

Comment: What if I have a return value as a Template as well how would I deal with it ?